# 2D Raycasting and rect collision in Pygame (Line of Sight, Obstacles)

Tags: python, pygame, 2d, collision-detection, raycasting

New programmer with three months of Python under my belt (only a few weeks of pygame)...

I'm designing a 2-D, top-down game and have been trying to get obstacles to break sprite LOS. My current attempt is for each sprite to cast a single ray toward every other sprite in visual range, stopping if the ray collides with a LOS blocker's rect, and adding only visible sprites to a list.

So far, the sprites always see one another through the wall. I thought it was an iteration/indentation/too-many-loops issue. I've tried boolean-type breaks and putting the code in a function with return (at several different points in the code), but it didn't help -- the monster always head straight for the player until they hit the wall.

**Picture**: [X-Ray Vision](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWnEC.jpg)

It's been a few days of Google research and trial and error, but no joy. Any solves or nudges in the right direction much appreciated!

Relevant code follows.

### Wall Class

**Implementation**

```
    wall = GraphBoxSprite('wall', (WIDTH // 2 - 25, HEIGHT // 2 - 10), 50, 20, BLACK, False, walls, obstacles, losBlockers, allSprites)
```

**Code**

```
class GraphBoxSprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    # Creates a sprite the size and shape of supplied graph size
    def __init__(self, ID, position, squareWidth, squareHeight, colour, transparent=False, *groups):
        super().__init__(*groups)
        self.ID = ID
        self.position = position
        self.image = pygame.Surface((squareWidth, squareHeight)) # Blank surface
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=position)
        self.image.fill(colour)
        if transparent is True:
            self.image.set_colorkey(colour) # Transparent background
```

### Creature Class

**Implementation**

```
    character = CreatureSprite('character', (WIDTH // 2, HEIGHT // 2 - 50), MEDIUM, QUICK, QUIET, BLUE_LINE, CANDLELIGHT, None, None, characters, allCreatures, allSprites)
```

**Code**

```
class CreatureSprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    # Creates a sprite to order
    def __init__(self, ID, position, size, speed, noiseLevel=None, colour=GREY, lightRadius=None, infravision=None, image=None, *groups):
        super().__init__(*groups)
        self.image = pygame.Surface(size) # Blank surface for image
        self.image.fill(WHITE)
        self.image.set_colorkey(WHITE) # Transparent background
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=position)

        self.ID = ID
        self.size = size
        self.colour = colour
        self.lightRadius = lightRadius

        self.losLength = 600 # view distance
        self.losWidth = 150 # degrees

        self.position = Vector2(position)
        self.speed = int(speed / (GRID_SCALE * 10))
        self.velocity = Vector2(0, 0)

        self.destination = Vector2(position)
        self.destinationRadius = 40
        self.heading = self.destination - self.position

        
    def update(self, walls, dungeonDressings, obstacles, losBlockers, monsters, characters, allCreatures, dungeonLights, creatureLights, allLights, allSprites):
        # Draw the creature
        pygame.draw.circle(self.image, self.colour, (self.size[0] // 2, self.size[1] // 2), self.size[0] // 2)
        pygame.draw.line(self.image, WHITE, (self.size[0] // 2, self.size[1] // 2), (self.size[0]  // 2, self.size[1] - 20), 1)


        # Draw light over darkness and colour over light
        if self.lightRadius:
            spritePosition = (int(self.position[0]), int(self.position[1])) # syntactic sugar
            pygame.draw.circle(DARKNESS, (COLOURKEY), spritePosition, self.lightRadius * GRID_SCALE)
            pygame.draw.circle(LIGHTNESS, (GOLDENROD), spritePosition, self.lightRadius * GRID_SCALE)


        # Movement
        self.position += self.velocity  # Update the position vector first
        self.rect.center = self.position  # Update the rect afterwards

        # This vector points to the destination
        self.heading = self.destination - self.position
        distance = self.heading.length()

        # Normalize heading for scale to desired length/speed below
        if self.heading: # Cannot normalize a zero vector
            self.heading.normalize_ip()
            
            # Sprite rotation to heading
            #self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.image, self.heading) --- won't accept Vector2, only real number ---

            # Slow down when approaching destination
            if distance > self.destinationRadius:
                self.velocity = self.heading * self.speed
            elif distance <= 15:
                for sprite in allSprites:
                    if sprite in allCreatures or sprite in obstacles: # Creatures maintain personal space
                        self.velocity = Vector2(0, 0)
            else:
                self.velocity = self.heading * (distance / self.destinationRadius * self.speed)


        # Line of Sight
        targets = []
        visible = []
        seen = []

        for target in allSprites:
            if target != self:
                targets.append(target.ID)
                lineOfSight = target.position - self.position
                lineOfSightDist = lineOfSight.length()
                
                if lineOfSightDist < self.losLength: # Target in range
                    #if self.heading < self.losWidth: # Target in field of view --- need to convert to comparable format ---
                    x = self.position[0]
                    y = self.position[1]

                    for i in range(int(lineOfSightDist)): # Try to reach target with a cast ray
                        x += lineOfSight[0]
                        y += lineOfSight[1]
                        
                        for sprite in allSprites:
                            if sprite.rect.collidepoint(int(round(x)), int(round(y))):
                                if sprite in losBlockers: # Stop ray
                                    seen.append(sprite)
                                    visible.append(target.ID)
                                    break
                                else:
                                    seen.append(sprite)
                                    visible.append(target.ID)
                                    break

        print('{} sees {} out of {} in range'.format(self.ID, visible, targets))
        

        # Creature AI
        if self.ID == 'monster':
            if seen:
                for sprite in seen:
                    if sprite.ID == 'character':
                        self.destination = sprite.position


        # When sprites collide
        for sprite in allSprites:
            if self.rect.colliderect(sprite):
                if self in allCreatures and sprite in obstacles:
                    self.velocity = Vector2(0, 0)


    def changeColour(self, colour):
        self.colour = colour
```

### Full Code

```
import os, sys, ctypes, random, math, copy, time, pickle, shelve, pprint, pygame # Inbuilt functions
import charReference, equipment # Reference material
from pygame.locals import *
from pygame.math import Vector2

pygame.init() 
pygame.display.set_caption('LOOT OR DIE!')

directory = 'C:\\Users\\user\\OneDrive\\LootOrDie\\'

pygame.font.init()


# Main fonts
font             = pygame.font.Font(directory + 'fonts\\Cour.ttf', 18)
fontB            = pygame.font.Font(directory + 'fonts\\Courbd.ttf', 18)
fontI            = pygame.font.Font(directory + 'fonts\\Couri.ttf', 18)
fontBI           = pygame.font.Font(directory + 'fonts\\Courbi.ttf', 18)
smallFont        = pygame.font.Font(directory + 'fonts\\Cour.ttf', 16)
smallFontB       = pygame.font.Font(directory + 'fonts\\Courbd.ttf', 16)
smallFontI       = pygame.font.Font(directory + 'fonts\\Couri.ttf', 16)
smallFontBI      = pygame.font.Font(directory + 'fonts\\Courbi.ttf', 16)
bigFont          = pygame.font.Font(directory + 'fonts\\Cour.ttf', 24)
bigFontB         = pygame.font.Font(directory + 'fonts\\Courbd.ttf', 24)
bigFontI         = pygame.font.Font(directory + 'fonts\\Couri.ttf', 24)
bigFontBI        = pygame.font.Font(directory + 'fonts\\Courbi.ttf', 24)


# Colours
COLOURKEY    = (127,  33,  33) # Transparent colour key

BLACK        = (  0,   0,   0)
WHITE        = (255, 255, 255)
DARKGREY     = ( 64,  64,  64)
GREY         = (128, 128, 128)
LIGHTGREY    = (200, 200, 200)

PINK_LINE    = (238, 106, 167)
RED          = (179,   0,   0)
BLOOD        = (138,   3,   3)
ORANGE       = (255, 185,   0)

GOLD         = (100,  84,   0)
GOLDENROD    = (212, 175,  55)
GREEN        = (  0, 130,   0)
FOREST_GREEN = ( 11, 102,  35)

BLUE_LINE    = (100, 149, 237)
BLUE_INK     = (  0,   0, 128)
DARK_BLUE    = (  0,  60, 120)



""" Define Screen """
# Prevent screen stretching
preventStretch = True
if preventStretch is True:
    user32 = ctypes.windll.user32
    user32.SetProcessDPIAware()


SCREEN_SIZE = WIDTH, HEIGHT = (1440, 900)
SCREEN = pygame.display.set_mode(SCREEN_SIZE, pygame.RESIZABLE) # FULLSCREEN

LEFT_MARGIN = 40
TOP_MARGIN = 26
LINE_HEIGHT = 22

COL1 = LEFT_MARGIN 
COL2 = int(SCREEN.get_width() / 4 + (LEFT_MARGIN * 2))
COL3 = int(((SCREEN.get_width() / 4) + (LEFT_MARGIN * 2)) * 2)
COL4 = int(((SCREEN.get_width() / 4) + (LEFT_MARGIN * 2)) * 3)


# Timing and FPS
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 60

# Double mouse-click half second delay
doubleClickClock = pygame.time.Clock()
DOUBLE_MOUSE_CLICK_TIME = 500 



""" Define Buttons """
MENU_BUTTON_WIDTH = 150
MENU_BUTTON_HEIGHT = 30

LINE_BUTTON_WIDTH = int(SCREEN.get_width() / 4 - (LEFT_MARGIN * 2))
LINE_BUTTON_HEIGHT = LINE_HEIGHT - 2

EQUIP_BUTTON_WIDTH = int(SCREEN.get_width() / 2 - (LEFT_MARGIN * 2))
BODY_BUTTON_WIDTH = 255

# TextLine Buttons
col_1_textLines = []
col_2_textLines = []
col_3_textLines = []

lineNo = 0
for line in range(40): # The maximum number of lines per screen
    line = COL1, TOP_MARGIN + LINE_HEIGHT * lineNo
    col_1_textLines.append(line)
    lineNo += 1

col_2_textLines = []
lineNo = 0
for line in range(40):
    line = COL2, TOP_MARGIN + LINE_HEIGHT * lineNo
    col_2_textLines.append(line)
    lineNo += 1

col_2_textLines = []
lineNo = 0
for line in range(40):
    line = COL2, TOP_MARGIN + LINE_HEIGHT * lineNo
    col_2_textLines.append(line)
    lineNo += 1



""" Dungeon Settings """
# Graph paper coordinates
GRID_SCALE    = 5 # feet per square
SQUARE_WIDTH  = 20
SQUARE_HEIGHT = 20
GRID_MARGIN   = 1 # between squares

# Creature Sizes
TINY   = (5, 5)
SMALL  = (10, 10)
MEDIUM = (15, 15)
LARGE  = (20, 20)
HUGE   = (40, 40)

# Creature Speeds and Noise Levels
""" Run is * 10 """
STATIONARY = SILENT      = 0
SHAMBOLIC  = STEALTHY    = 15
SLUGGISH   = QUIET       = 30
SLOW       = NOISY       = 60
PLODDING   = LOUD        = 90
QUICK      = CACOPHONOUS = 120

# Light Source Radii
CANDLELIGHT       = 10
SMALL_ITEMLIGHT   = 10
MEDIUM_ITEMLIGHT  = 15
LONG_ITEMLIGHT    = 20
LANTERNLIGHT      = 30
TORCHLIGHT        = 40

# Cloak screen in darkness
DARKNESS = pygame.Surface(SCREEN_SIZE)
DARKNESS.set_colorkey(COLOURKEY)

# Mask for light colour
LIGHTNESS = pygame.Surface(SCREEN_SIZE)
LIGHTNESS.set_colorkey(COLOURKEY)


def dungeon():
    # Window for testing
    windowSize = windowWidth, windowHeight = WIDTH, HEIGHT
    window = pygame.Surface(windowSize)

    """ Sprite Groups """
    # Dungeon
    walls = pygame.sprite.Group()
    dungeonDressings = pygame.sprite.Group()
    obstacles = pygame.sprite.Group() # Anything that blocks movement
    losBlockers = pygame.sprite.Group() # Anything that blocks line of sight (LOS)

    # Creatures
    characters = pygame.sprite.Group()
    monsters = pygame.sprite.Group()
    allCreatures = pygame.sprite.Group()

    # Lights
    dungeonLights = pygame.sprite.Group()
    creatureLights = pygame.sprite.Group()
    allLights = pygame.sprite.Group()

    # Everything
    allSprites = pygame.sprite.Group()


    """ Sprites """
    # Character sprites
    character = CreatureSprite('character', (WIDTH // 2, HEIGHT // 2 - 50), MEDIUM, QUICK, QUIET, BLUE_LINE, CANDLELIGHT, None, None, characters, allCreatures, allSprites)

    # Enemy sprites
    for monster in range(1):
        orc = CreatureSprite('monster', (WIDTH // 2, HEIGHT // 2 + 50), MEDIUM, PLODDING, NOISY, BLOOD, TORCHLIGHT, None, None, monsters, allCreatures, allSprites)

    # The Wall
    wall = GraphBoxSprite('wall', (WIDTH // 2 - 25, HEIGHT // 2 - 10), 50, 20, BLACK, False, walls, obstacles, losBlockers, allSprites)


    selectedObject = None
    destinationPoint = None


    while True: # Main Loop
        clock.tick(FPS) # Set framerate

        # Capture mouse coordinates on screen and in window
        mousePos = x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos() 
        mouseWindowPos = (x - int(WIDTH / 2 - windowWidth / 2), y - int(HEIGHT / 2 - windowHeight / 2))

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                    if selectedObject:
                        if selectedObject in characters:
                            selectedObject.changeColour(BLUE_LINE)
                        elif selectedObject in monsters:
                            selectedObject.changeColour(BLOOD)
                        selectedObject = None
                    else:
                        quitGame()

            # Set destination with mouse-click
            if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                # Check for double click event
                doubleClick = False
                if doubleClickClock.tick() < DOUBLE_MOUSE_CLICK_TIME:
                    doubleClick = True

                if event.button == 1:
                    if selectedObject: # Single-click to de-select sprite
                        if selectedObject in characters:
                            selectedObject.changeColour(BLUE_LINE)
                        elif selectedObject in monsters:
                            selectedObject.changeColour(BLOOD)
                        selectedObject = None

                    elif not selectedObject: # Single-click to select new sprite
                        for sprite in allCreatures:
                            if sprite.rect.collidepoint(mouseWindowPos):
                                selectedObject = sprite
                                selectedObject.changeColour(GOLDENROD)

                elif event.button == 3:
                    if selectedObject: # Send selected sprite to destination
                        selectedObject.destination = mouseWindowPos


        # Arrange dark and light sources
        DARKNESS.fill(0)
        LIGHTNESS.fill(COLOURKEY)

        # Draw squares on coloured background to mimic graph paper
        window.fill(BLUE_LINE)
        for column in range(SQUARE_WIDTH + GRID_MARGIN, windowWidth, SQUARE_WIDTH + GRID_MARGIN):
            for row in range(SQUARE_HEIGHT + GRID_MARGIN, windowHeight, SQUARE_HEIGHT + GRID_MARGIN):
                pygame.draw.rect(window, WHITE, [column, row, SQUARE_WIDTH, SQUARE_HEIGHT])

        # Update Sprites
        allSprites.update(window, walls, dungeonDressings, obstacles, losBlockers, monsters, characters, allCreatures, dungeonLights, creatureLights, allLights, allSprites)

        # Draw items
        walls.draw(window)
        allCreatures.draw(window)

        # Draw screen overlaid with darkness overlaid by lit areas
        SCREEN.blit(window, (WIDTH // 2 - windowWidth // 2, HEIGHT // 2 - windowHeight // 2))

        # Make LIGHTNESS surface partially transparent
        LIGHTNESS.set_alpha(75)
        SCREEN.blit(LIGHTNESS, (0, 0))
        SCREEN.blit(DARKNESS, (0, 0))
        pygame.display.update()



class GraphBoxSprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    # Creates a sprite the size and shape of supplied graph size
    def __init__(self, ID, position, squareWidth, squareHeight, colour, transparent=False, *groups):
        super().__init__(*groups)
        self.ID = ID
        self.position = position
        self.image = pygame.Surface((squareWidth, squareHeight)) # Blank surface
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=position)
        self.image.fill(colour)
        if transparent is True:
            self.image.set_colorkey(colour) # Transparent background



class CreatureSprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    # Creates a sprite to order
    def __init__(self, ID, position, size, speed, noiseLevel=None, colour=GREY, lightRadius=None, infravision=None, image=None, *groups):
        super().__init__(*groups)
        self.image = pygame.Surface(size) # Blank surface for image
        self.image.fill(WHITE)
        self.image.set_colorkey(WHITE) # Transparent background
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=position)

        self.ID = ID
        self.size = size
        self.colour = colour
        self.lightRadius = lightRadius

        self.losLength = 600 # view distance
        self.losWidth = 150 # degrees

        self.position = Vector2(position)
        self.speed = int(speed / (GRID_SCALE * 10))
        self.velocity = Vector2(0, 0)

        self.destination = Vector2(position)
        self.destinationRadius = 40
        self.heading = self.destination - self.position

        
    def update(self, walls, dungeonDressings, obstacles, losBlockers, monsters, characters, allCreatures, dungeonLights, creatureLights, allLights, allSprites):
        # Draw the creature
        pygame.draw.circle(self.image, self.colour, (self.size[0] // 2, self.size[1] // 2), self.size[0] // 2)
        pygame.draw.line(self.image, WHITE, (self.size[0] // 2, self.size[1] // 2), (self.size[0]  // 2, self.size[1] - 20), 1)


        # Draw light over darkness and colour over light
        if self.lightRadius:
            spritePosition = (int(self.position[0]), int(self.position[1])) # syntactic sugar
            pygame.draw.circle(DARKNESS, (COLOURKEY), spritePosition, self.lightRadius * GRID_SCALE)
            pygame.draw.circle(LIGHTNESS, (GOLDENROD), spritePosition, self.lightRadius * GRID_SCALE)


        # Movement
        self.position += self.velocity  # Update the position vector first
        self.rect.center = self.position  # Update the rect afterwards

        # This vector points to the destination
        self.heading = self.destination - self.position
        distance = self.heading.length()

        # Normalize heading for scale to desired length/speed below
        if self.heading: # Cannot normalize a zero vector
            self.heading.normalize_ip()
            
            # Sprite rotation to heading
            #self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.image, self.heading) --- won't accept Vector2, only real number ---

            # Slow down when approaching destination
            if distance > self.destinationRadius:
                self.velocity = self.heading * self.speed
            elif distance <= 15:
                for sprite in allSprites:
                    if sprite in allCreatures or sprite in obstacles: # Creatures maintain personal space
                        self.velocity = Vector2(0, 0)
            else:
                self.velocity = self.heading * (distance / self.destinationRadius * self.speed)


        # Line of Sight
        targets = []
        visible = []
        seen = []

        for target in allSprites:
            if target != self:
                targets.append(target.ID)
                lineOfSight = target.position - self.position
                lineOfSightDist = lineOfSight.length()
                
                if lineOfSightDist < self.losLength: # Target in range
                    #if self.heading < self.losWidth: # Target in field of view --- need to convert to comparable format ---
                    x = self.position[0]
                    y = self.position[1]

                    for i in range(int(lineOfSightDist)): # Try to reach target with a cast ray
                        x += lineOfSight[0]
                        y += lineOfSight[1]
                        
                        for sprite in allSprites:
                            if sprite.rect.collidepoint(int(round(x)), int(round(y))):
                                if sprite in losBlockers: # Stop ray
                                    seen.append(sprite)
                                    visible.append(target.ID)
                                    break
                                else:
                                    seen.append(sprite)
                                    visible.append(target.ID)
                                    break

        print('{} sees {} out of {} in range'.format(self.ID, visible, targets))
        

        # Creature AI
        if self.ID == 'monster':
            if seen:
                for sprite in seen:
                    if sprite.ID == 'character':
                        self.destination = sprite.position


        # When sprites collide
        for sprite in allSprites:
            if self.rect.colliderect(sprite):
                if self in allCreatures and sprite in obstacles:
                    self.velocity = Vector2(0, 0)


    def changeColour(self, colour):
        self.colour = colour



def quitGame():
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()



def waitForKeyPress():
    # Pause program until a key is pressed
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN or event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                return



""" Start Game """
if __name__ == '__main__':
    dungeon()
```

Comment: What is `position`?  A vector?  Does `lineOfSightDist` look correct?  In your test-case is the `lineOfSight` variable `(0,-1)` - sure it's looking the right way?  (not say in `+Y`)

Comment: position is the (x,y) position of the sprite. lineOfSight is really a heading (I wanted a different term for this variable than the existing self.heading). I'm sure they're looking the right way since the sprites do see one another--they're looking at each other too well, in fact--right through the wall!

Answer (score 3):

I can't see just from looking at a section of the static code why your program does not work, it seems like it should.

I can however, offer my own solution though:

For each NPC/opponent:

- Calculate the *line* between each [NPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-player_character) and the Player.  Here we just use the centre of the sprite rectangle because it's easy.  Think of this as the "ray" if you like.
- Determine if any Wall/Blocker object lies on this line/ray.

  - If so, the line of sight is broken, and we can stop checking.

So the line of sight is simply (Player-x, Player-y) to (NPC-x, NPC-y), defining a *line*.

Each Wall object is *four lines* (forming a rectangle), so we check for intersection of the Player-NPC line with each of the rectangle-side lines.  This simplifies the check down to some linear geometry with no trigonometry or square-roots.  There's also no need to "walk" along the line-of-sight checking for occlusions, once anything is found on the line, that NPC can't see the Player.

Note: we do *not* check for NPCs occluding the vision of other NPCs, by design.

[image: line_of_sight demo]

Reference Code:

```
import pygame
import random

WINDOW_WIDTH = 800
WINDOW_HEIGHT= 600
SURFACE = pygame.HWSURFACE|pygame.DOUBLEBUF|pygame.RESIZABLE

#define colour
WHITE = ( 200, 200, 200)
GREY  = ( 50, 50, 50)
BLACK = (0,0,0)
RED   = ( 200, 0, 0 )
GREEN = (0,255,0)
TAN   = (240,171,15)
YELLOW= (255,255,0)


def lineRectIntersectionPoints( line, rect ):
    """ Get the list of points where the line and rect
        intersect,  The result may be zero, one or two points.

        BUG: This function fails when the line and the side
             of the rectangle overlap """

    def linesAreParallel( x1,y1, x2,y2, x3,y3, x4,y4 ):
        """ Return True if the given lines (x1,y1)-(x2,y2) and
            (x3,y3)-(x4,y4) are parallel """
        return (((x1-x2)*(y3-y4)) - ((y1-y2)*(x3-x4)) == 0)

    def intersectionPoint( x1,y1, x2,y2, x3,y3, x4,y4 ):
        """ Return the point where the lines through (x1,y1)-(x2,y2)
            and (x3,y3)-(x4,y4) cross.  This may not be on-screen  """
        #Use determinant method, as per
        #Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93line_intersection
        Px = ((((x1*y2)-(y1*x2))*(x3 - x4)) - ((x1-x2)*((x3*y4)-(y3*x4)))) / (((x1-x2)*(y3-y4)) - ((y1-y2)*(x3-x4)))
        Py = ((((x1*y2)-(y1*x2))*(y3 - y4)) - ((y1-y2)*((x3*y4)-(y3*x4)))) / (((x1-x2)*(y3-y4)) - ((y1-y2)*(x3-x4)))
        return Px,Py

    ### Begin the intersection tests
    result = []
    line_x1, line_y1, line_x2, line_y2 = line   # split into components
    pos_x, pos_y, width, height = rect

    ### Convert the rectangle into 4 lines
    rect_lines = [ ( pos_x, pos_y, pos_x+width, pos_y ), ( pos_x, pos_y+height, pos_x+width, pos_y+height ),  # top & bottom
                   ( pos_x, pos_y, pos_x, pos_y+height ), ( pos_x+width, pos_y, pos_x+width, pos_y+height ) ] # left & right

    ### intersect each rect-side with the line
    for r in rect_lines:
        rx1,ry1,rx2,ry2 = r
        if ( not linesAreParallel( line_x1,line_y1, line_x2,line_y2, rx1,ry1, rx2,ry2 ) ):    # not parallel
            pX, pY = intersectionPoint( line_x1,line_y1, line_x2,line_y2, rx1,ry1, rx2,ry2 )  # so intersecting somewhere
            pX = round( pX )
            pY = round( pY )
            # Lines intersect, but is on the rectangle, and between the line end-points?
            if ( rect.collidepoint( pX, pY )   and
                 pX >= min( line_x1, line_x2 ) and pX <= max( line_x1, line_x2 ) and
                 pY >= min( line_y1, line_y2 ) and pY <= max( line_y1, line_y2 ) ):
                pygame.draw.circle( window, WHITE, ( pX, pY ), 4 )
                result.append( ( pX, pY ) )                                     # keep it
                if ( len( result ) == 2 ):
                    break   # Once we've found 2 intersection points, that's it
    return result



class Wall( pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    """ Rectangular objects that blocks line-of-sight """
    def __init__( self, x, y, width, height ):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__( self )
        self.image = pygame.Surface( ( width, height ) )
        self.rect  = self.image.get_rect();
        self.rect.topleft = ( x, y )
        self.image.fill( TAN )

    def getRect( self ):
        return self.rect
        

class Being( pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    """ Some kind of creature with miraculous 360 degree vision """
    def __init__( self, x, y, colour=YELLOW, size=48 ):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__( self )
        self.colour= colour
        self.image = pygame.Surface( ( size, size ), pygame.SRCALPHA )
        self.rect  = self.image.get_rect();
        self.rect.center = ( x, y )
        self.size  = size
        self.seen  = False
        self.update()

    def update( self ):
        """ If we've been seen, go red with embrassment """
        if ( self.seen ):
            colour = RED
        else:
            colour = self.colour
        pygame.draw.circle( self.image, colour, ( self.size//2, self.size//2 ), self.size//2 )

    def setSeen( self, seen=True ):
        self.seen = seen

    def getCentre( self ):
        return self.rect.center

    def getRect( self ):
        return self.rect




### initialisation
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode( ( WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT ), SURFACE )
pygame.display.set_caption("Line of Sight")

# Occluders
wall_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
central_block = Wall( WINDOW_WIDTH//3, WINDOW_HEIGHT//2, WINDOW_WIDTH//3, 20 )  # top middle (random)
wall_sprites.add( central_block )

# NPCs
npc_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
for i in range( 3 ):
    npc_sprites.add( Being( random.randint( 50, WINDOW_WIDTH-50 ), 50, GREEN ) )

# Player
player_sprite = pygame.sprite.GroupSingle()
player = Being( WINDOW_WIDTH//2, 3*WINDOW_HEIGHT//4 )  # bottom middle
player_sprite.add ( player )


### Main Loop
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
done = False
while not done:

    # Handle user-input
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if ( event.type == pygame.QUIT ):
            done = True
        elif ( event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP ):
            # On mouse-click
            pass

    # Movement keys
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if ( keys[pygame.K_LEFT] ):
        player.rect.x -= 1
    if ( keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] ):
        player.rect.x += 1
    if ( keys[pygame.K_UP] ):
        player.rect.y -= 1
    if ( keys[pygame.K_DOWN] ):
        player.rect.y += 1


    # Update the window, but not more than 60fps
    window.fill( BLACK )

    # Check to see if the Player can see any NPCs
    player_centre = player.getCentre()
    for npc in npc_sprites:
        npc_centre = npc.getCentre()
        # Does the line <player> to <npc> intersect any obstacles?
        line_of_sight = [ player_centre[0], player_centre[1], npc_centre[0], npc_centre[1] ]
        found = True
        for wall in wall_sprites:
            # is anyting blocking the line-of-sight?
            intersection_points = lineRectIntersectionPoints( line_of_sight, wall.getRect() )
            if ( len( intersection_points ) > 0 ):
                found = False
                break # seen already
        # Highlight anyone found
        npc.setSeen( found )
        if ( found ):
            pygame.draw.line( window, WHITE, player_centre, npc_centre )
        else:
            pygame.draw.line( window, GREY, player_centre, npc_centre )
                
    # draw the sprites
    wall_sprites.draw( window )
    npc_sprites.update()
    npc_sprites.draw( window )
    player_sprite.draw( window )

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick_busy_loop(60)


pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Ooh, neat. I'm going to analyze this and see if I can get it working in my code--I'll let you know. Thanks for the info!

Comment: I added my full code, in case you're interested in seeing where I've gone wrong.

Comment: Well crap--your code in my program creates the same issue: monster runs straight at character and into wall! It's got to be something else in my code screwing this up.  I added a pause feature after each lineRectIntersectionPoints() and it gave me this:  [(720, 440)]  []  []  monster sees ... (all the things)

Comment: @Chimera1013 It's not something simple, like having the check-logic inverted, so it sees when it shouldn't?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the input, all. The solution was indeed a bug in my active code, @Kingsley.

While the unseen sprites are still being added to the list of what's seen, I was able to add a single line at the end to remove an unseen sprites from the list.

It's gratifying to know my original code *was* working, but your visual lines of sight helped me isolate the issue, improve my sprite system, and develop a more robust raycasting system--so thank you!

You'll find `visible.remove ( target )` at the end of the Line of Sight for loop:

```
while True: # Main Loop
    # Capture mouse coordinates on screen and in window
    mousePos = x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos() 

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                if selectedObject:
                    if selectedObject in characters:
                        selectedObject.selected = False
                    selectedObject = None
                else:
                    quitGame()

        # Set destination with mouse-click
        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            # Check for double click event
            doubleClick = False
            if doubleClickClock.tick() < DOUBLE_MOUSE_CLICK_TIME:
                doubleClick = True

            if event.button == 1:
                if selectedObject: # Single-click to de-select sprite
                    if selectedObject in characters:
                        selectedObject.selected = False
                    elif selectedObject in monsters:
                        selectedObject.selected = False
                    selectedObject = None

                if not selectedObject: # Single-click to select new sprite
                    for sprite in allCreatures:
                        if sprite.rect.collidepoint( mousePos ):
                            selectedObject = sprite
                            selectedObject.selected = True

            if event.button == 3:
                if selectedObject: # Send selected sprite to destination
                    selectedObject.destination = mousePos

    # Refresh the screen
    clock.tick( FPS ) # Set framerate
    window.fill( WHITE )

    # Arrange dark and light sources
    DARKNESS.fill( 0 )
    LIGHTNESS.fill( COLOURKEY )

    # Draw Graph Paper
    window.fill( BLUE_LINE )
    for column in range( 0 + GRID_MARGIN, WIDTH, SQUARE_WIDTH + GRID_MARGIN ):
        for row in range( 0 + GRID_MARGIN, HEIGHT, SQUARE_HEIGHT + GRID_MARGIN ):
            pygame.draw.rect( window, WHITE, [column, row, SQUARE_WIDTH, SQUARE_HEIGHT] )

    # Check for creature line of sight
    targets = []
    visible = []
    for viewer in allCreatures:
        viewerCenter = viewer.getCenter()
        for target in allCreatures:
            targetCenter = target.getCenter()
            targets.append(target)

            # Does the line of sight intersect any obstacles?
            lineOfSight = [ viewerCenter[0], viewerCenter[1], targetCenter[0], targetCenter[1] ]
            seen = True

            for blocker in losBlockers:
                # Is anything blocking line of sight?
                intersectionPoints = lineRectIntersectionPoints( lineOfSight, blocker.getRect() )
                if ( len( intersectionPoints ) > 0 ):
                    seen = False
                    break # seen already

            # Highlight anyone found
            target.setSeen( seen )

            if ( seen ):
                pygame.draw.line( window, RED, viewerCenter, targetCenter )
                visible.append( target )
            else:
                pygame.draw.line( window, GREY, viewerCenter, targetCenter )
                if target in visible:
                    visible.remove ( target )
    
        # Creature AI
        if viewer.ID == 'monster':
            if visible:
                for sprite in visible:
                    if sprite.ID == 'character':
                        viewer.destination = sprite.position

    # Update Sprites
    allSprites.update( obstacles, allCreatures, allSprites )

    # Draw items
    allSprites.draw( window )

    # Make LIGHTNESS surface partially transparent
    LIGHTNESS.set_alpha( 75 )
    window.blit( LIGHTNESS, ( 0, 0 ) )
    window.blit( DARKNESS, ( 0, 0 ) )

    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: @Kingsley - do you see anything in this live code that would cause the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a way of doing it right here.
I this what you want?:

```
import pygame
import random

Randomx = random.randint(1,450)
Randomy = random.randint(1,450)

Wallx = Randomx - 50
Wally = Randomy

screen = pygame.display.set_mode([500,500])

x = 225
y = 225
running = True

while running:
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    screen.fill([255,255,255])
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        #move
        x -= .2
        #make shure it isn't off the screen
        if x <= 0:
            x = 0
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        x += .2
        if x >= 450:
            x = 450
    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        y -= .2
        if y <= 0:
            y = 0
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        y += .2
        if y >= 450:
            y = 450
    #Red's Vision
    vision1 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, [0,0,0], (0,y,500,50))
    vision2 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, [0,0,0], (x,0,50,500))
    #-----------------------------------------------
    #Red
    red = pygame.draw.rect(screen, [255,0,0], (x,y,50,50))
    #Blue
    blue = pygame.draw.rect(screen, [0,0,255], (Randomx,Randomy,50,50))
    #Wall
    wall = pygame.draw.rect(screen, [0,255,0], (Wallx,Wally,25,50))
    #Collisoin Detection/Vision
    if vision1.colliderect(blue):
        SeeBlock = True
        if x >= Randomx:
            w = x - Randomx
        if x <= Randomx:
            w = Randomx - x
        if x >= Randomx:
            vision3 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, [0,0,0], (x,y,-w,50))
            if vision3.colliderect(wall):
                SeeBlock = False
        if x <= Randomx:
            vision3 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, [0,0,0], (x,y,w,50))
            if vision3.colliderect(wall):
                SeeBlock = False
        red = pygame.draw.rect(screen, [255,0,0], (x,y,50,50))
        blue = pygame.draw.rect(screen, [0,0,255], (Randomx,Randomy,50,50))
        wall = pygame.draw.rect(screen, [0,255,0], (Wallx,Wally,25,50))
        if SeeBlock == True:
            print("I SEE IT!")
        
    if vision2.colliderect(blue):
        SeeBlock = True
        if y >= Randomx:
            w = y - Randomy
        if y <= Randomx:
            w = y + Randomy
        if y >= Randomy:
            vision3 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, [0,0,0], (x,y,-w,50))
            if vision3.colliderect(wall):
                SeeBlock = False
        if y <= Randomy:
            vision3 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, [0,0,0], (x,y,w,50))
            if vision3.colliderect(wall):
                SeeBlock = False
        red = pygame.draw.rect(screen, [255,0,0], (x,y,50,50))
        blue = pygame.draw.rect(screen, [0,0,255], (Randomx,Randomy,50,50))
        wall = pygame.draw.rect(screen, [0,255,0], (Wallx,Wally,25,50))
        if SeeBlock == True:
            print("I SEE IT!")
    pygame.display.flip()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                running = False
                pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks, it's a different way of going about it. I'll have to analyze your code to see if it works with my code. If I can't get raycasting to work, I'll be taking another look at using rects as vision boxes.